# Creating new dataframe from existing - SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, chained-assignment

I have a csv file that I import as a dataframe. This dataframe goes through multiple filtering steps. Data is also moved between columns based on conditionals.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_csv_file.csv', names=headers)
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['Column_X'])
series1 = df2.loc[df2['Column_Y'] == 'Category1', 'Column_X']
df2.loc[df2['Column_Y'] == 'Category1', 'Column_Z'] = series1
...
```

After the last line is entered into the command prompt, I get the SettingWithCopyWarning.

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer, col_indexer] = value instead.
```

Notice that I used .loc in my code.

Doing the following does not throw an error:

```
df.loc[df['Column_Y'] == 'Category1', 'Column_Z'] = series1
```

Which makes me think the problem is in using df2 as a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that `df2` is a view of `df1`.  Instead put a `.copy()` at the end of the `.drop_duplicates` call.

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['Column_X']).copy()
```